# Basic example in diagram chasing

Tags: category-theory, diagram-chasing

> Consider the following diagram:
>
> [image]
>
> Given that $h \circ f = k$ and $l \circ h = g$, prove that $ g \circ f = l \circ k $
>
> Answer:
> [image]
> page-35, An introduction to Category Theory, Harold Simmons

I am a bit confused, doesn't the first diagram itself have the proof? It is pretty clear that moving by $k$ then by $l$ gives same thing as moving by $f$ and $g$ to me. So, what more of an idea is put in the step wise proof?

Comment: When one is introducing such diagrams, one might define them by saying that every triangle (but only triangles) within the diagram represents a composition relation among functions. This proof is teaching that triangle relations imply relations corresponding to larger polygons as well.

Comment: Hi! I think I get what you mean and it has helped me  but I feel like something is missing still.

Comment: Why is it clear to you without the step-by-step proof? Does your reasoning involve $h$? Are you using the given relations involving $h$? If not, then your argument is invalid. Just because $gf$ and $lk$ have the same endpoints (i.e. domain and codomain) doesn't mean they are the same function.

Comment: Well suppose you draw out the premise relation, then you get the first diagram. Now, the first diagram is the statement we want to prove, so I don't see why we should do anything further. I don't see why the step wise thing must be done @Karl

Comment: Could you elaborate on the last point @Karl

Comment: Call the leftmost dot $A$ and the rightmost dot $B$. There may be many morphisms from $A$ to $B$. Two arrows (or paths) from $A$ to $B$ are not necessarily the same morphism. The task in this problem is to prove that $gf$ and $lk$ are in fact the same morphism.

Comment: Oh I think I see now @Karl

Comment: @Karl I think u made thypo i nsecond one

Answer (score 4):

I think you are being falsely reassured by the picture of the diagram, which makes things seem like they are obvious. But imagine you are given a group $G$, and elements $f,g,h,k,l\in G$ such that $h\cdot f=k$ and $l\cdot h =g$. Now you want to prove that $g\cdot f = l\cdot k$. Of course, it's easy:
$$g\cdot f=(l\cdot h)\cdot f = l\cdot (h\cdot f) = l\cdot k,$$
but it's clear that it requires this computation to give the proof. You would not get away with saying "it's just clear".

The visual dimension of diagrams is extremely useful, but you should not forget that in the end it's just a shortcut for a lot of formal equations, and that any "visual reasoning" is justified by computations. The computation you're looking at is basically saying that in a diagram, as long as all triangles commute, then everything commutes.

Comment: You've proven it using computation but that doesn't mean you need computation to prove I believe

Comment: Math is not based on what you believe.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: The burden of proof is on you. This computation provides a proof. Can you provide a proof without it? Your position seems to be "I find it obvious and I don't feel like it needs a proof". You have the right to feel that. Just like someone can say "I personally find the Riemann hypothesis completely trivial and I don't understand why people want a proof". But if you find something obvious then you should be able to prove it, just like one can prove that $2+3=5$ (given the correct definitions). Otherwise we're not doing maths but religion.